# Azure Logic App Get Targeted Worksheet row values

Tags: excel, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

Scenario. I have `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`, I only want to get the `Sheet2` data cause I will be converting it to `HTML`. However I want to do it without signing to `Excel`'s `OneDrive` or using the excel action.

The reason why I can't login to `Excel`'s `OneDrive` because of multi-factor authentication/credentials issue.

Is there any way I can get the worksheet values using the file content from get file `OneDrive` flow and not signing in to excel business flow?

[image: File content used to attached in email]

Comment: I think `Get File Content`  of Onedrive only gives you the content of the file as a whole but doesn't allow you to read anything within it. It's mostly used to copy a file from Onedrive to another location.

Comment: @KedMardemootoo yah right sir. is there any other way? cause when i'm adding an action excel(one drive) it requires you for signin in. But my company credentials don't work though due to multiple verifications. So any suggestions?

Comment: But using Onedrive you would still need to login right? You could try to setup an action to copy the file from OneDrive to Azure Storage, then from Azure Storage you could attempt to read it but I never tried that, not sure it will work. Same logic could apply for SharePoint but if you're limited with the credentials. Another way would be to request a service account with a strong password but without multi-factor authentication.

Comment: Yes let's hope someone else can come up with one - i'm curious too. By the way you should edit your question to provide the reason as to why you can't sign in. Someone might even provide you with an answer to fix that bit and all sorted out. The more info you provide/the clearer it is, the easier you'll get someone who can give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `OneDrive` in `Azure logic app`, you must first create a connection to it, otherwise you cannot operate it.

[image]